# Is there ever a good reason to share accounts to a computer?

Tags: account-security

I work for an organization that seems to have awful IT practices, especially when it comes to security. I noticed most people do not lock their computers when they are away from the desk. I asked why this is and they told me that since accounts are shared everyone knows the password anyway. This is true, the IT department setup accounts to be shared. I think part of the reason may have been because workers often rotate between positions and rotate between computers. For example different people take turns working at the front desk so they share the same account. There is no domain (partly because if the mix of different OSs) so all the accounts are local.

Is it ever OK for accounts to be setup and used like this? In past jobs it was considered extremely important to lock computes and not share passwords. Am I being too rigid in my thinking in that other organizations may do it differently? I tried talking to my coworkers about setting things up differently and they were very unperceptive and did not see any need to change what has always been done. It was almost hard to talk about because to me it was as apparent as wearing a seat belt is a good idea when driving and it's hard for me to understand why someone couldn't see the point.

Comment: "Is it okay?" depends on okay for what. It's clearly usable. Is it good InfoSec? Absolutely not. But unless there is an incident, IT will just claim "It has always worked. No need to change now."

Comment: Are you in any way (made) responsible for this situation?

Comment: @Marcel I'm new and in the IT department. No one else in it seems to think these types of things are a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Security measures are always a trade-off: more security is usually in the way, i.e. comes with less usability, less efficiency etc. This is even more true if the workflows are not designed with security in mind but security is just thrown into existing workflows.

This means security measures cause costs of reduced productivity, in addition to the more obvious costs of initial and regular costs for rolling out security products, time needed for maintaining security (software updates, education, ...) etc. Security can also impact the ability to compete on the market, since it results in increased prices for the offered products and services and might limit the flexibility or time to market.

From a business perspective such costs must be compared against the potential costs caused by a compromise if these security measures are not in place. The result of this comparison might be that it is more important to be efficient and competitive for now, than to protect against losing business due to security incidents. This is especially true for companies trying to enter a market, which don't actually face the risk of losing business since they don't have any business yet to begin with. That's why these companies have a high [risk appetite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_appetite).

Apart from that there are environments where the risk is actually low and a more restrictive security does not add relevant protection. This might be isolated environments where due to other measures like physical access control only a few employees could use the systems anyway.

Comment: Just to point out there was no physical access control and lots of people working in the same area.

Comment: @FizzBop The relevant question is if shared accounts are *better* than not sharing. How much damage can one do, compared to the amount saved?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the concept of ***personal accounts***, rather than shared accounts, is that as an organisation you want/need ***separation of duties*** where specific persons or a team  is assigned roles and ***made responsible*** for their  specific tasks and held ***personably accountable*** and nobody else. To achieve that you typically need an IT architecture that supports that.

In a very small organisation such separation of duties is usually not a concern. Often out of necessity people wear many different hats and everybody interacts directly with everybody else and simply "knows" who's (been) doing what, everybody is trusted implicitly to do the right thing for a common goal.
And often in parallel people have "their job" that is theirs alone and nobody else is allowed to that.

That small organisation culture is often reflected in their IT systems as well. Often at the start there simply is no IT architecture, no central management, no centralised authentication etc. at all. Equipment and software gets bought and installed as needed and when there is no centralised authentication your only choice is that local account, which of course can quickly become a shared account when others share the same duty.

When the organisation starts to grow, there usually comes a transition, often difficult for the founder(s) and first employees, where the organisation gets reshaped, teams and departments get formed and responsibilities assigned and removed. That is usually also where you ensure that no single person is solely responsible for particular tasks and everybody has (in theory) an assigned backup to take over when required.

That is usually the moment where a newly created IT department follows and facilitates the changes in organisation and is tasked to embed those changed organisation structures and authorisations in new centralised and managed IT systems.
That is the moment where you ensure for example that HR data no longer lives only on the head of HR's workstation and set up that from now on the whole HR department (and only that department) gets access to payroll data/systems, only the sales team is allowed to adjust prices and send out quotes etc. etc.

You really don't want to drive such a business change (solely) from the IT department at your own initiative. Such changes are often painful as people are frequently resistent to change.

> Is there ever a good reason to share accounts to a computer?

In addition that: "when there is simply no centralised IT yet" and continued legacy as explained above,  some examples:

- Software (licenses) often follow a freemium model and/or pricing strategy where the single user version/license comes with fewer features but also fewer requirements and often most importantly: at much lower cost than the enterprise version and/or multi-user license.

  When certain (expensive) software is only used occasionally it might be significantly cheaper to not install it on all workstations, but rather as the single user version on a single workstation and when you need to use that software, you do so at that dedicated workstation as that one named user.

  A single user version might for example use a flat text file as its database, where the multi-user version might require a proper database server to ensure safe concurrent usage and an LDAP/AD server for role assignments.
- When the computer is the controller for directly attached equipment.
  You don't want to be in a position where a job started by one person can't be paused/stopped by another operator because the controller is password locked with a personal account.